# how to create a nice horizontal scroll area for app screenshots, like the one for apps on iTunes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have some app screenshots I'd like to add to my website, but I'd like to but them in a horizontal scroll area just like the iTunes Store app screenshots area.

How can I implement this or can someone point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a DIV with this as CSS:

```
.overflowdiv {
    height: 310px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    width: 980px;
}
```

This will create a 980x310px div with an auto overflow so it will automatically add a scroll if the content is wider than the amount of pixels.

To prevent 'new lines' from happening, I usually add a table in it:

```
<div class="overflowdiv">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Content here
        </td>      
        <td>
            Content here
        </td>      
        <td>
            Content here
        </td>      
        <td>
            Content here
        </td>      
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: how do i get rid of the white background behind the scroll bar?

Answer (score 2):

```
<div style="width: 800px; height: 100px; overflow: auto">
   <div style="height: 100px">
      ... lots of content here ...
   </div>
</div>
```

as long as you style the "content" so it flows horizontally, it'll create a horizontal scrollbar once the inner div grows wider than 800px and "overflows" the outer div.